# Can't stream from server with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, vlc

I'm trying to stream something from a linux VPS to the VLC player on my Windows computer.
I opened the 5000 port with iptables, it looks like this:

```
 iptables -L -n
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000
 ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5000

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000
 ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5000
```

I don't think the repetition is a problem.
I'm starting gstreamer with

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -m videotestsrc ! x264enc  ! rtph264pay  ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

The last message that I get says

```
Got message #44 from element "pipeline0" (state-changed): GstMessageStateChanged, old-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_PAUSED, new-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_PLAYING, pending-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_VOID_PENDING;
```

I guess it should be playing if it says `new-state=(GstState)GST_STATE_PLAYING`

When I open in Windows Power shell with this command

```
./vlc.exe rtsp://139.162.141.241:5000
```

It gives me `VLC is unable to open the MRL`
If I open `rtsp://139.162.141.241:5000` in the browser it doesn't appear to download anything.
The problem should be related to `gst-launch` but can't figure it out.
Any hints for debugging this situation?
Thanks

---

I also tried `udpsink` instead of `tcpserversink`
Trying with different `host` doesn't help either
Also installed ubuntu desktop on the server and tried to open vlc player this way and didn't work
Before I tried streaming from an mp4 file like so

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -m  filesrc location = sample.mp4 ! qtdemux ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

This didn't work either

Comment: well first tip is to use netcat to sniff on port to check if anything is coming `nc -l 5000`, better to use Linux as client for that..